# qt5: Error class QTextBrowser’ has no member named ‘setMarkdown

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to build a code from github but it gives error when the run the command sudo make. Please help. Also my qmake --version is

````
Using Qt version 5.14.2 in /opt/qt514/lib```
````

```
    AboutDialog.cc
/home/admin/delegate/Degate/src/GUI/Dialog/AboutDialog.cc: In constructor ‘degate::AboutDialog::AboutDialog(QWidget*)’:
/home/admin/delegate/Degate/src/GUI/Dialog/AboutDialog.cc:92:19: error: ‘class QTextBrowser’ has no member named ‘setMarkdown’
   92 |         changelog.setMarkdown(in_changelog.readAll());
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DegateCore.dir/build.make:3419: CMakeFiles/DegateCore.dir/src/GUI/Dialog/AboutDialog.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/delegate/Degate/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:132: CMakeFiles/DegateCore.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/delegate/Degate/build'
make: *** [Makefile:133: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Show us which GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/DegateCommunity/Degate

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't use the Qt version you posted above but an older one - [setMarkdown()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#markdown-prop) was added in 5.14.

Comment: I ran the command qmake --version and it gives me what i posted.

Comment: Why are you building as `root` with `sudo`?  And what's the output of `sudo qmake --version`?

Comment: Can you try 5.15? It is possible that it was introduced in 5.14 after 5.14.2. Either way, the project should set the required Qt version, so they have got a bug you can report.

Comment: with using sudo, it says CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied and qmake ---version gives QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.14.2 in /opt/qt514/lib

Comment: Can you try 5.15? 5.15 has no repository for focal. So not able to install

Comment: On a side note, do not use sudo. It is not a good idea.

Comment: OP abandoned the thread again?

Comment: No. Nothing got banned. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

This was introduced in Qt 5.14 according to [this ticket](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72349).

So, you are most likely using an older version. I would, in any case, advise you to use at least Qt 5.15. Even that version is only getting P0/P1 fixes at this point in time, let alone older versions. It is also an LTS version.

Degate has also got a bug that they should set the required Qt version in their project so that there are no surprises for their consumers.

Comment: 5.15 has no repository for focal. So not able to install

Comment: Not sure what focal is, but just download the Qt installer from the website. You do not need a repository for this.